# mysql select row with fallback

Tags: mysql, magento2

I need to fetch a row from a table,
if there is value in store_id = 1 return the row,
otherwise, return the row store_id = 0.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` 
WHERE (store_id = 1 OR store_id = 0) 
AND attribute_id = 67
```

Comment: Is this expected to return exactly one row or are there many possible per `store_id`?

Comment: only one row - if store 1 exists return it, otherwise return value from store 0

Answer (score 1):

Using limit

```
SELECT * 
FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` 
WHERE (store_id = 1 OR store_id = 0) 
AND attribute_id = 67
order by store_id desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution was something like this:

```
SELECT *, IF(store_value.value IS NULL, default_value.store_id, store_value.store_id) AS `store_id` FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `default_value` LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `store_value` ON store_value.attribute_id = 67 AND store_value.store_id = 1 WHERE default_value.attribute_id = 67 AND default_value.store_id = 0
```

Thanks for help